# Access query to a macro enabled excel template using vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Im trying to put data from a query which requires a parameter into a excel template with marcos in it however I keep getting errors. Im getting the parameter from the form.
heres my code:

```
Private Sub exportButton_Click()
Dim XL As Excel.Application
Dim wbTarget As Workbook

Dim qdfResults As QueryDef
Dim rsResults As Recordset

'Set up refernce to the query to export

Set qdfResults = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MarksQuery")
qdfResults.Parameters("Forms!comp!competition") = Forms!comp!competition

'Execute Query
Set rsResults = qdfResults.OpenRecordset()


'reference excel
Set XL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'refernce workbook
Set wbTarget = XL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documen…\folder\resultTemplate.xltm")

'clear excel sheet
wbTarget.Worksheets("marktable").Cells.ClearContents

'paste data from query to worksheet
wbTarget.Worksheets("markTable").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordSet rsResults

'save workbook
** 1) 'wbTarget.SaveAs ("C:\Users\user\Documents
\folder\resultTemplate1.xlsm") 
** 2) wbTarget.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\user\Documents\folder\resultTemplate1.xlsm",                                                            

FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled

'clear variables
Set wbTarget = Nothing
Set XL = Nothing
Set qdfResults = Nothing
End Sub
```

with 1) i could get the data into a work book but without the macros
with 2) i can get the data in and macro but wont save properly

any suggestions?

EDIT**
by wont save properly i mean that it is creating a temperory file that i cannot save
and now it wont even created that, now its creating a file with 0 bytes and no type

cant answer by own question yet but until I can heres my working code:

The only problem I can see was that wbTarget.Close and XL.Quit werent used which caused the module to still run and the file therefore wasn't completely saved but temporary. Credit to @Gord Thompson

```
Private Sub exportButton_Click()

Dim XL As Excel.Application, wbTarget As Workbook
Dim qdfResults As QueryDef
Dim rsResults As Recordset

Set XL = New Excel.Application
Set wbTarget =    XL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\folder\ResultsTemplate.xltm")

Set qdfResults = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MarksQuery")
  qdfResults.Parameters("Forms!comp!competition") = Forms!comp!competition
Set rsResults = qdfResults.OpenRecordset()

wbTarget.Worksheets("markTable").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordSet rsResults

wbTarget.SaveAs "C:\Users\user\Documents\folder\Results.xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
wbTarget.Close
Set wbTarget = Nothing
XL.Quit


End Sub
```

Comment: You have a copy/paste syntax error in qdfResults.Parameters("Forms!comp!competition = Forms!comp!competition
, please correct it before we can see something for you.

Comment: I just tried "Option 2" and it worked fine for me. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19890933/edit) your question to explain what you mean by "won't save properly".

Comment: The test code that works for me is in the pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/UeWEWhxX). Try it and see if it works for you (once you've updated the file paths). Note that my test code includes `wbTarget.Close` and `XL.Quit` statements.

Comment: Again, you have not close the parenthesis: qdfResults.Parameters(, and what's this: wbTarget.Worksheets("marktable").Cells…, and what's that: wbTarget.Worksheets("markTable").Cells… 1).CopyFromRecordSet rsResults ... You'd first compiler the VBA before run it.

Comment: @GordThompson I tried your code and i think it worked but when i added in the query i wanted to pass in the same thing happened : A temp file created then another hidden excel file named "zzzXltmTest.xlsm" but its hidden. Then when i try to open it i get the error in excel : " Excel cannot open the file '~zzzXltmTest.xlsm' because the file format or file extension is not vaild. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file

Comment: @jacouh i think that should be it fixed now didnt realise it wasnt pasting properly. the 1) and 2) arent in the actual code just me showing the 2 methods ive tried

Comment: @GordThompson got it working ! your code helped so much thank you. Ill add my working code to the original post

Comment: Good to hear that it's working. Rather than editing your question, please post an answer to show the working code and explain what the problem was. (It's perfectly OK to answer your own question.)

Comment: ohh i didnt know i could answer my own thank you

Comment: Sorry, I thought that anyone could answer their own question. I added an answer for you.

Comment: @GordThompson if you have less than 10 reputation you have to wait 8 hours from when the question was asked before answering your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can see was that wbTarget.Close and XL.Quit werent used which caused the module to still run and the file therefore wasn't completely saved but temporary. Credit to @Gord Thompson

```
Private Sub exportButton_Click()

Dim XL As Excel.Application, wbTarget As Workbook
Dim qdfResults As QueryDef
Dim rsResults As Recordset

Set XL = New Excel.Application
Set wbTarget =    XL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\folder\ResultsTemplate.xltm")

Set qdfResults = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MarksQuery")
  qdfResults.Parameters("Forms!comp!competition") = Forms!comp!competition
Set rsResults = qdfResults.OpenRecordset()

wbTarget.Worksheets("markTable").Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordSet rsResults

wbTarget.SaveAs "C:\Users\user\Documents\folder\Results.xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
wbTarget.Close
Set wbTarget = Nothing
XL.Quit


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange behaviour in Office automation projects can often be the result of failing to properly `Close` objects and `Quit` applications. In this case adding

```
wbTarget.Close
```

and

```
XL.Quit
```

statements appears to have resolved the issue.